# Not another one: EOF error message in LeetCode, works fine in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

I am brand new to Python3 coding, so I hope you bear with me and my question. I have found similar questions on stackoverflow and other sites but I still wasn't able to solve the issue:

When I run the following code in Visual Studio, everything is fine, no error message, nothing.
In LeetCode on the other hand, I get an EOF error pointing at the very first input line.

> Error message:EOFError: EOF when reading a line
> num = input("Enter a number: ")
> Line 4 in intToRoman (Solution.py)
> ret = Solution().intToRoman(param_1)
> Line 56 in _driver (Solution.py)
> _driver()
> Line 67 in  (Solution.py)

The code is as follows:

```
class Solution:
num = ""
def intToRoman(self, num: int) -> str:
    num = input("Enter a number: ") 
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(num)
            if num < 0 or num > 3999:  # if not a positive int or inout larger than 3999 print message and ask for input again
                print("Sorry, input must be a positive integer and smaller than 3999, try again")
                continue
            break
        except ValueError:
            return("That's not an int!") # else all is good, number is >=  0 and an integer

Ones = ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", ""] # list of single digit roman numbers 
Tens = ["X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC", ""] # list of double digit roman numbers
Hundreds = ["C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM", ""] # list of three digit roman numbers
Thousands = ["M", "MM", "MMM", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""] # list of four digit roman numbers
if (len(str((num)))) == 1:
    print (Ones[int(repr(num)[-1]) - 1])
if (len(str((num)))) == 2:
    print (Tens[int(repr(num)[-2]) - 1] + Ones[int(repr(num)[-1]) - 1])
if (len(str((num)))) == 3:
    print (Hundreds[int(repr(num)[-3]) - 1] + Tens[int(repr(num)[-2]) - 1] + Ones[int(repr(num)[-1]) - 1])
if  (len(str((num)))) == 4:
    print (Thousands[int(repr(num)[-4]) - 1] + Hundreds[int(repr(num)[-3]) - 1] + Tens[int(repr(num)[-2]) - 1] + Ones[int(repr(num)[-1]) - 1])
```

Thanks for any kind of feedback, including what to optimise in this code.

Comment: Check your file encoding and line endings (Linux LF vs Windows CR+LF)

Comment: I haven't tried to solve a problem in LeetCode, so I'm not sure how it supposed to work. But the problem is that you are asking for input but `sys.stdin` has been closed. Are you supposed to be getting data from stdin? Have you already read stdin somewhere else? You could remove all of the code you've shown after the call to `input`. Either you don't get the data that way or something before you called this method already consumed it.

Comment: The "while True: convert str to int" is insane. It would be enough to convert a given str just once.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback up till now.

Comment: sorry, the comment wasn't finished yet. The class definition "class Solution" in line 1 as well as the parameters of the function in line 3 were kind of given. I just copied and pasted the rest out of my macOS Visual Studio. I'll have a look at the line endings @Grismar

Comment: Pardon my beginners question @tdelaney but where did I close sys.stdin? I am not familiar yet with sys.stdin. I am not expecting any input other than the user input of a positive integer not larger than 3999. The result is then the same number with Roman numbers/ lettres. And as already mentioned, it works fine in VS

Comment: `input()` reads `sys.stdin` - that's the input pipe to the program, it reads the things you type as the program runs. Since you got End of File (EOF) that means that `sys.stdin` has been closed. I don't know LeetCode so I don't know how it passes the test data. My guess is that when it starts you code, it writes a single line to the process stdin and then coses it. If that is the case, then something read that line before we got to this function. Maybe this code was accidentally called twice. The thing is, its the code _before_ this code that is the problem.... (guessing!)

Comment: I had expected that a couple of my lines are "insane" :-) That line you are referring to though, wasn't from me, it was part of the given code <br/><pre> <code> class Solution:
    def intToRoman(self, num: int) -> str:

Comment: If you're curious enough to take a sneak peek:

Comment: [LeetCode Integer to Romans] (https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-to-roman/)